# How can I make a requirements.txt that points to a git repo, but use a local version of the package if it exists?

Tags: git, docker, pip

I have a `requirements.txt` that refers to a package that's hosted on an internal gitlab server (e.g., `git+ssh://git@srv/pkgs/mypkg.git@v1#egg=mypkg`). `pip i -r requirements.txt` works when I'm doing a development build because the gitlab server has my credentials. When I run `pip i -r requirements.txt` *inside my docker image*, it fails because git cannot authenticate with the server. Ideally, I don't want the docker image to store any ssh keys.

I'm trying to solve this by having a "pre-docker" make target, which will run `pip download -r requirements.txt`. The Dockerfile will instruct docker to copy all of the packages into the container, which will then do a `pip i` with `--find-links=file:///app/pip-cache` (`/app/pip-cache` being where I'll store my container-localized packages). This doesn't seem  to work; it looks like pip does not account for `--find-links` when it's fetching from a **remote git repository**, so it still fails when trying to authenticate with the remote server even though the package is in `/app/pip-cache`.

I assume `pip` has no idea that the package in `/app/pip-cache` is the same as the package I'm requesting from my gitlab server. *(?)*

Is there any way to hint to `pip` inside `requirements.txt` that this `git+ssh://` package can also be found locally? Otherwise, is there another, more suitable solution to this problem?

Comment: I ended up packaging up a wheel and deploying it to a local server and using `find-links` with my `http://wheelhouse`, but I still would like to get this approach to work if possible because it's much lower maintenance.

Comment: I don't think it's possible to do declaratively.

Answer (score 0):

The most common way to clone a private git repository inside a Docker image is to ssh keys. You can enable ssh cloning on the repository using your ssh key. You then copy this ssh key inside the image, and
clone the repository using ssh.

The problem with this approach is that the keys will be part of the image, and if you share the image, anyone can retreive your ssh keys form the images layers (even if you delete the keys when done).
There are multiple solutions for this issue. One option would be to use the `--squash` option to docker build, to squash the docker layers into a single layer. This will avaoid leaking the ssh keys from build layers.

Another better approach is to use [Docker multi-stage builds](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/eng-image/multistage-build/). You basically pull the code into the first image using ssh or username/pass auth. You then copy the code into the base image. Tha advantage here is that
the cloning process is not part of the resulting image, and thus secretes won't leak with the Docker image.